# Do users get put off if they enter their FULL Date of Birth in a form?

Tags: forms, user-interface, usability, date

I wonder if it is a good idea (and in a quirky funny way) to just get the user to enter this:

**Month-of-Birth:** (Month) (Year)

Where (Month) and (Year) is a drop down box which user just pick the month and year.

I feel that this way, they would be more inclined to fill up the form since I did not go for the (Day).

What do you guys think?

How valueable is collecting (Day) field to you?

Thanks. Peace.

Comment: Unless you need it for Coppa compliance, getting asked for my birthday on a website is like being asked for my zip code when I buy batteries. I just want the batteries. I don't want to be target-marketed too.

Comment: Most women would be happy to give you day and month but not year... :)

Comment: lol Marjan, not entirely true. Women over 30 these days actually do tell you their age. In the end I decided to just get the age in a textbox.. and then store data as BirthYear immediately. I think that is the best way so people don't get annoyed with entering their DOB since entering two digits is the most painless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, in these situations (all are different) the only way you can truthfully know the answer is to do some [A-B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing), anything else is personal opinion and guess work.  Provide a form that has two (or more) differently layouts and measure which one has the better conversion.  If you can, then this is a great thing to do as an ongoing project.  Does the form convert better laid out slightly differently, with different text or even colours.

Answer (score 1):

I find the use of drop-down boxes to enter a year to be significantly worse for usability than entering the day.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you feel the need to alert them of their birthday or you are trying to enforce exact age I don't really see a reason for day.